# Two Classes Using Each Other

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

The test-case code it pretty self-explanatory. So basically, is something like this possible to do without the use of `.cpp` files?

```
class A
{
public:

    static int i;

    static void test(void)
    {
        std::cout << "B::i = " << B::i << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:

    static int i;

    static void test(void)
    {
        std::cout << "A::i = " << A::i << std::endl;
    }
};

int A::i = 1;
int B::i = 2;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A::test();
    B::test();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `A::test()` and `B::test()` outside.

```
class A
{
public:
    static int i;
    static void test(void);
};

class B
{
public:
    static int i;
    static void test(void);
};

int A::i = 1;
int B::i = 2;

void A::test(void)
{
    std::cout << "B::i = " << B::i << std::endl;
}

void B::test(void)
{
    std::cout << "A::i = " << A::i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Damnit I knew that! Why do you always have to forget stuff when you actually need it!

Comment: You can give the reasons rite. So everyone will understand easily.